# Generating a day of year column from date column in R?

Tags: r, date, posixct

I am attempting to take a column of the format POSIXct (or, if necessary, chr) and generate a new column that represents the day of year for that date (some number from 1-366, depending on the year). For example, say I have a row with value "2020-11-16" in the format POSIXct, how can I extract the day of year (day 321 in this case) and do so over the course of an entire column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can use the lubridate- Package

```
> library(lubridate)
> yday(as.POSIXct("2020-11-16"))
[1] 321
```

of course this also works with a vector/ column:

```
v<-paste0("2020-11-",1:30)
yday(as.POSIXct(v))
```